# Visual studio 2017 Tizen wearable project can't be created

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tizen

I have Visual studio 2017 community edition and I have recently installed Tizen studio for it. Everything works with Tizen package manager, emulator and sdb command but I cant create new project for Tizen in Visual studio 2017. I got error "missing imports" after I create a new project and my log file is displayed here. How do I fix my problem?

```
 ----- CompositionError level 1 ------
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.DefaultTypeScriptWorkspace.ctor(typeScriptWorkspaceCore): expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:
    Contract name: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.ITypeScriptWorkspaceCore
    TypeIdentityName: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.ITypeScriptWorkspaceCore
but found 0.
   part definition Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.TypeScript.ScriptContexts.DefaultTypeScriptWorkspace

Microsoft.NodejsTools.TestAdapter.TestMethodResolver.ctor(discoverer): expected exactly 1 export matching constraints:
    Contract name: Microsoft.NodejsTools.TestAdapter.TestContainerDiscoverer
    TypeIdentityName: Microsoft.NodejsTools.TestAdapter.TestContainerDiscoverer
but found 0.
   part definition Microsoft.NodejsTools.TestAdapter.TestMethodResolver
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks very weird that messages about TypeScript and NodeJS are shown when you create the Tizen ***C#*** project o_O IMHO, the creation command for other project types would not work neither.

Most likely reason is broken installation of SDK. Would you try re-install of TypeScript and NodeJS SDK with Visual Studio Installer?

Comment: Thanks for that answear and I will try to re-install Typescript and NodeJS sdk. I can create others project without problems but not Tizen project.